# I want to match two columns against each other in excel

Tags: excel, vbo

I want to compare two columns named Debit and Credit to check that every transaction amount in Debit column is present in the Credit column. I have used a MATCH and VLOOKUP but they only match transactions in Debit against the Credit but I need to also match transactions in the Credit against the debit at the same instance.[image]

Comment: You figured how to MATCH. Put an IF in it looking for a value in the Credit column. If yes: your formula, if not match the other way around

Comment: In theory your approach would only check for a  single instance and could cancel each other out. Example is you had two transactions of $100, but your credit was missing one (so two debits and ONE credit for 100)... it wouldn't be obvious that it was missing.

Comment: Hello, You are right and you saw this far before i could realize it. I am currently using this formula: "=IF(ISBLANK(A2),IFERROR("Debit transaction n°" & MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$21,0)+1, "Debit transaction not found!"),IFERROR("Credit transaction n°" & MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$21,0)+1, "Credit transaction not found!"))"               But it would match 2 debits against of same value against one credit, while i don't want it to do that. I need something that would work with the concept of every debit must have a corresponding credit. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, put the formule below in C2 and drag it all the way down.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),IFERROR("Debit transaction n°" & MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$21,0)+1, "Debit transaction not found!"),IFERROR("Credit transaction n°" & MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$21,0)+1, "Credit transaction not found!"))
```

[image]

##### EDIT :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),IF((IF(B2<>"",(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,$B2)=1)+0,0))=1,IFERROR("Debit transaction n°"&MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$24,0)+1,"Debit transaction not found!"),"Debit transaction not found!"), IF((IF(A2<>"",(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1)+0,0))=1,IFERROR("Credit transaction n°"&MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$24,0)+1,"Credit transaction not found!"),"Credit transaction not found!"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this, very helpful. However i have a small issue now. If i have a case where there are three similar values, one in debit and two in credit, i want to make sure that it only matches one of them in credit and the other value in credit says Debit Transaction not found.

Comment: You're welcome. If you mean by _one of them_ the first instance of the value, I put an EDIT in the end of my answer above. Check it out !

Comment: Hi Thank you again. I just checked this out and it works for this case but wouldn't work in a scenario where i have 4 similar values, in a scenario like that, i would want to match them together. The concept is that for every credit, there must be a corresponding debit.